# casting from double to integer variable

Tags: casting, integer, double

I wrote this program in Dev C++ IDE. I was expecting it might get crash. but it is displaying the right output. can some please explain how the memory gets allocated here.why this is working.

```
int main()
{
     int i=10;
     double d=3333333.555 ;
     i=d+d;
     printf(" Value of I after assignment %d",i);
     getch();
}
```

Comment: How the memory gets allocated for what? This is simple addition.

Comment: for example: int i; double d=3333333.555; i = int (d);

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the order of operations is 3333333.555 + 3333333.555 (addition operator), resulting in 6666667.11 (still a double). The result is then cast to an int (assignment operator), causing a truncation of the value to 6666667. Is that the value you're expecting?

Comment: sorry, I think the above  behavior is correct. because I was using Windows 7 OS, which is 64bit. I tried to give big values in 'd' ie.,(111113333333.555) then it is printing the value  -2147483648. Now please explain how this situation is handle. In UNIX Integer take 4 bytes  to store the value, but double takes 8 bytes. so when a variable is avalue greater than 64687. then how double value gets stored in that int variable.

Comment: What are you asking about exactly? Why doesn't it crash? How memory is allocated? Explanation of the result value? What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

In C, local variables and parameters are held in registers and in the stack. That means that as long as you have available space in the stack, they will be put there, with no explicit allocation.

In fact, all the programs start with a stack allocated by default, that's why there's no need for the C program to request more memory.

How does the stack work? well... in general there's a register for holding a pointer to a chunk of memory. Whenever you enter in a function, that register is moved so that it now points to a free portion of the stack, and when you leave that function, the old value of the stack register is restored.

The inner workings are a bit more trickier, but that's the general idea.